# Link Azure devops repos and boards

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-repos, azure-boards

Hi am new to Azure devops and try to understand Repos and Boards. 
Is there a way to link both (i.e Azure Repos and Azure Boards)
Any pointers would be useful. 
Basically, I want to understand whether code commits can be connected to link Boards tasks or User story.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can link work items with user stories. You can find useful information here: [Linking Work Items to Git Branches, Commits, and Pull Requests](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/)

Answer (score 0):

You can link a work item to a pull request.

[image]

And you can link a lot of items to a work item.  [image]